# Understanding Time complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I am just starting to learn the big O concept. What I learned is that if a function f is less than or equal to another constant multiple of function g, then f is O(g).

Now I came across an example in which a string of size "n" takes "2n" (double the size of input) steps of algorithm. So they say the time taken is O(2n) but then they follow this statement by saying  As O(2n)=O(n), time complexity is O(n).

I dont understand this. As 2n will always be greater than n, how can we ignore the multple of 2 then? Anything less than or equal to 2n will not necessarily be less than n!

Doesn't it mean that we are somehow equating n and 2n? Sounds confusing. Please clarify in simplest possible way as I am just a beginner in this concept. 
Best Regards :)

Comment: Asymptotic calculation is done by the calculation of limits. An estimate closer to the real deal with T(n).

Comment: f(n)=2n, g(n)=n, f<=2*g.

Answer (score 2):

*... As 2n will always be greater than n, how can we ignore the multple of 2 then? ...*

Simply put, with growing `n` the multiplier loses its importance. The *asymptotic* behavior of a function describes what happens when `n` gets large.

Maybe it helps to consider not just `O(n)` and `O(2n)`, because they are in the same class, but to contrast it with some [other common classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities). Example: Any `O(n^2)` algorithm will take longer than any `O(n)`, **in the long run** (in the short run, their running times might even be reversed). Say you have two algorithms, one with linear time complexity of `100n` and another with `8n^2`. The quadratic algorithm will be faster for all `n =< 12`, but slower for all `n > 12`.

This property – that for **any** fixed nonnegative `c` and `d` you'll find an `n`, so that `cn < dn^2` – constitues a part of the hierarchy of time complexities.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O and related notations are intended to capture the aspects of algorithm performance that are most inherent to the algorithm, independent of how it is being run and measured.

Constant multipliers depend on the unit of measurement, seconds vs. microseconds vs. instructions vs. loop iterations. Even measured in the same units they will be different if measured on different systems. The same algorithm may take 20n instructions in one instruction set, 30n instructions on another. It may take 0.5n microseconds on one, 10n microseconds on another.

Many of the basic algorithm complexities you will see in the literature were calculated decades ago, but remain meaningful across significant changes in processor architecture and even more significant changes in performance.

Similar considerations apply to start-up and similar overheads.

A `f(n)` is `O(n)` if there exist constants N and c such that, for all `n>=N, f(n) <= cn`. For f(n) = 2n the constants are `N=0` and `c = 2`. The first constant, N, is about ignoring overhead, the second, c, is about ignoring constant multipliers.

Answer (score 1):

As you alluded to in your first paragraph, the time required to execute the algorithm is proportional to a constant multiple of the input size. You can think of O(n), to be O(C*n), where C is any *constant* multiplier.